# Replacement character (�) is coming in Libra Office whereas as "'" in Google spreadsheet in CSV file

Tags: ubuntu, unicode

Why I am seeing different data in CSV file at different places?

I have a CSV file. When I open it in libra office in ubuntu 18.04, I see �  (replacement character) symbol in some cell.

**For example:** "India�s capital is Delhi". Whereas when I am opening the same file in google sheets, the content of cell displayed is "India's capital is Delhi". 
How is it that it is showing different values in both places and how can I resolve it?

**libra office**: "India�s capital is Delhi"

**Google sheets:** "India's capital is Delhi"

Comment: try replacing all `�` with `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not an apostrophe (character code 39) but a `right single quotation mark`.

This character looks like this:

```
’
```

Apostrophes are automatically changed to this character in MS Office packages, and Google 'office' faithfully displays Unicode characters without complaint.

The reason you would be seeing a replacement character (�) instead of the characted may be due to encoding issues.

Whereas an apostrophe is character code 39 (and ASCII), the right single quotation mark is a Unicode character (number `U+2019`).

Unless Libra office support this, it would show as an invalid character.  Incidentally, U+2019 is not supported on web pages either and will also show as a replacement character.